# Cannot select items in an accordion style menu

Tags: java, selenium, menu, accordion

It is the most bizarre thing.  I have been using XPATH to choose different menu options  (I have Eclipse NEON & latest Selenium)

You can see in the attached images, I can select the first 3 links with XPATH beautifully.  Why would the last three fail?  I will include the code also.  I tried just find the link and that does not work either.

```
    <div id="rightColumn">
                <div class="simplemenu accord ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" id="accordion" role="tablist">
                    <h5 class="headerbar first ui-accordion-header ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active" role="tab" id="ui-id-1" aria-controls="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">Films &amp; Versions</h5>
                    <div style="display: block;" class="ui-accordion-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-accordion-content-active" id="ui-id-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/filmAdmin.php"><img src="/images/film.png" border="0"> Film Admin</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/filmVersionAdmin.php"><img src="/images/film_link.png" border="0"> Film Version Admin</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/filmVersionMaccsCode.php"><img src="/images/film_error.png" border="0"> Film versions without DCHub ref</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/filmVersionsWithNoTers.php"><img src="/images/film_save.png" border="0"> Film Versions With No Territories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/matchFilmVWithMPS.php"><img src="/images/film_go.png" border="0"> Match Film Version With MPS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/maccsCPLNames.php"><img src="/images/magnifier_zoom_in.png" border="0"> Duplicate MACCS Film Strings</a></li>
                        </ul>
                            </div>
```

[Trying to select any of the last three with XPATH fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7vva.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReSIe.png)

Comment: You don't show the xpaths that you're using.  How are you accessing the two that are accessible?  I would think that //a[contains(.,"Film Versions With No Territories")] would work, for example.  Perhaps you're checking for equals and not spotting the leading space?

Comment: Please take a minute to properly indent the HTML you posted so that it's easier to read. Also post the code you have tried that works and the stuff that doesn't work. What happens when it doesn't work? Post any error messages or describe in what was it "doesn't work."

Comment: thank you so far.  I thought that my HTML did get formatted correctly.  I will share examples of the  XPATH code I am using but first I am going to try using the CSS code asnwer given below

Comment: Correction it seems now that I look at it again that only the FIRST item in the list is working  **FILM ADMIN**, in all the others we get: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

I will post the XCODE I got for the first two using Firebug.  Again the first one works the second one does not.


**Film Admin** keyslink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a"));

**Film Version Admin**

//keyslink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a"));

Comment: Sorry I figured out line break afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Try using following element locators to locate your last 3 elements:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#rightColumn > div div >ul li:nth-child(3) > a"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#rightColumn > div div >ul li:nth-child(4) > a"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#rightColumn > div div >ul li:nth-child(5) > a"));
```

Comment: I think it is working ... and who know maybe the XPATH would have worked.  First I tried your CSS and only the first one worked.  The I put in a thread.sleep after clicking on Films & Versions to give a little time for the accordion to open up an VOILA!